# AngularJS routeProvider redirecting doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have index page, which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="libraryApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Angular Library</title>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="page/js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="page/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="page/js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="page/js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('libraryApp', ['ngRoute', 'libraryControllers']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'page/booksList.html',
            controller: 'booksListController'
        })
        .when('/library/bookDetails/:bookId', {
            templateUrl: 'page/bookDetails.html',
            controller: 'bookListController'
        });
}]);
```

Controller:

```
var libraryControllers = angular.module('libraryControllers', ['libraryServices']);


    libraryControllers.controller('booksListController', function($scope, $http, BookFactory){

            BookFactory.getAllBooks()
            .success(function(response){
                $scope.books = response;
            });

            $scope.bookIsNotSelected = false;

            $scope.selectedBook = { id: 0 };

            $scope.showDetails = function(){

                if ($scope.selectedBook.id == 0){
                    $scope.bookIsNotSelected = true;
                }
                else {
                    BookFactory.showDetails($scope.selectedBook.id);
                }
            };  
        });
```

And services.js:

```
var services = angular.module('libraryServices', []);

services.factory('BookFactory', function($http) {

    var bookFactory = {};

    bookFactory.getAllBooks = function() {
        return $http.get('getBooksList');
    }

    bookFactory.showDetails = function(bookId){
        var request = 'library/bookDetails/' + bookId;
        return $http.get(request);
    };

    return bookFactory;
});
```

My problem is when I click button with showDetails() ng-click function, I send request to the Spring Rest Controller to get specfied book data. Everything works fine, I get JSON object, but my routeProvider doesn't redirect me to page/bookDetails.html page.

[image]

As you can see Http GET request is proper. I cant figure out why it doesn't redirecting me to bookDetails.html page. Any idea guys? I stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically making an ajax request would not change URL in browser, you need to use `$location` service to redirect between the routes(don't forget to inject `$location` dependency in controller function).

You should use `$location.path` to redirect to specified path.

```
bookFactory.showDetails = function(bookId){
    var request = 'library/bookDetails/' + bookId;
    return $location.path(request);
};
```

Rather you could have `href` on your anchor tag instead of having `ng-click` directive

```
<a ng-href="/library/bookDetails/{{obj.bookId}}">Show Details</a>
```

This would solve your problem fully. You should create a new controller for bookDetails page rather than using `booksListController`(which disobey single responsibility principle) which can be named as `bookDetailsController` so the details route will change to below.

```
.when('/library/bookDetails/:bookId', {
   templateUrl: 'page/bookDetails.html',
   controller: 'bookDetailsController'
});
```

Now `bookDetailsController` will have the logic to load the book details through ajax call. Basically there would be one method which will read a parameter from URL using `$routeParmas` service like `$routeParams.bookId` & will pass the bookId to server to retrieve the book detail.

Comment: This would throw an error, since you did not inject `$location` into the controller.

Comment: @AvijitGupta sir this is thumb rule in angular that you should inject dependency before using it.. I don't think so I should mention that in answer..

Comment: You know about that, I know about that, but maybe the other people seeing this post don't.

Comment: @AvijitGupta never-mind, I udpated answer(still it was pointless).. Thanks :)

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you. Of course I've created new controller for bookDetails following SRP :)

Comment: @G.Spansky Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: eee I don't know. It wasnt me bro.

Comment: @G.Spansky np..Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

A redirect does NOT occur when you make a HTTP GET call, it occurs when you change the url on the client-side:

Inject `$location` into your controller:

```
libraryControllers.controller('booksListController', function($scope, $http, BookFactory, $location){
```

Then use it as is:

```
$scope.showDetails = function(){
   if ($scope.selectedBook.id == 0){
      $scope.bookIsNotSelected = true;
   }
   else {
     BookFactory.showDetails($scope.selectedBook.id).then(function(res) {
        // Redirect occurs here..
        $location.path('library/bookDetails/' + $scope.selectedBook.id);
     });
   }
 };
```